# Python Pandas converting Date

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a graph with Dates on the x-axis but get the data not converted correctly.

Using the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as dates

df = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv')
df.drop('ID', axis='columns', inplace = True)

df_min = df[(df['Date']<='2014-12-31') & (df['Date']>='2004-01-01') & (df['Element']=='TMIN')]
df_min.drop('Element', axis='columns', inplace = True)
df_min = df_min.groupby('Date').agg({'Data_Value': 'min'}).reset_index()
print(df_min[:5])

df_max = df[(df['Date']<='2014-12-31') & (df['Date']>='2004-01-01') & (df['Element']=='TMAX')]
df_max.drop('Element', axis='columns', inplace = True)
df_max = df_max.groupby('Date').agg({'Data_Value': 'max'}).reset_index()
print(df_max[:5]) 

date_min = dates.date2num(df_min['Date'])

#plt.figure
#plt.plot(df_min, '-o', df_max, '-x')
```

Data has the following structure
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMKIe.png

Using parse_dates=['Date'] during read file I do get an date error.
But plotting of the graph I only get

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fd23cd3a048>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fd23a9a17b8>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fd23a7d6b00>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fd244286da0>]
```

Why do I no see a graph?

Comment: try using `pd.to_datetime` to convert the `Date` column natively to `datetime[64]ns`

Comment: you can use **parse_date**  `pd.read_csv('*.csv', parse_dates=['date'])` when loading csv